# digispark not printing simbol \,

Tags: arduino, attiny

i am having trouble with writing a \ symbol in digikeyboard.printIn, the line stops highlighting and outputs a error

D:\documents\Arduino\powershell_write.ino: In function 'void loop()':

powershell_write:67:24: error: incomplete universal character name \U

DigiKeyboard.println("$path = 'C:\Users\Public\passwords.png'");

```
                    ^
```

powershell_write:92:24: error: incomplete universal character name \U

DigiKeyboard.println("$ReportEmail.Attachments.Add('C:\Users\Public\passwords.png')");

```
                    ^
```

exit status 1
incomplete universal character name \U

thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the `\`:

```
DigiKeyboard.println("$path = 'C:\\Users\\Public\\passwords.png'");
```

Or use forward slashes if allowed:

```
DigiKeyboard.println("$path = 'C:/Users/Public/passwords.png'");
```